'Error :project ID request rate exceeded' on deploying contracts to Sepolia Test Network using command truffle migrate --reset --network sepolia
I have Ethereum Blockchain application(DAPP) using truffle framework with React as Frontend
I want to deploy my contracts to sepolia test network so I run

truffle migrate --reset --network sepolia

but I got an Error :
Error: project ID request rate exceeded
at /home/myProject/node_modules/truffle-hdwallet-provider/dist/webpack:/truffle-hdwallet-provider/Users/gnidan/src/work/truffle/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/provider.js:18:1
My truffle.config.js is as follows :
require('babel-register')
require('babel-polyfill')

const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const MNEMONIC = "MNEMONIC_HERE"
const INFURA_API_KEY = "API_KEY"

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",// Match any network id
    },
    sepolia: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, INFURA_API_KEY),
      network_id: '11155111',
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      networkCheckTimeout: 999999,  
      skipDryRun: true 
    },
    
  },
  contracts_directory:'./src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory:'./src/truffle_abis',

  solc: {
    version:"0.5.16",
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
    }
  }
}

Versions used
Truffle v5.4.6 (core: 5.4.6)
Node v14.21.2
truffle-hdwallet-provider ^1.0.17
How to resolve this?
